# c++: why can't I see changes of an object variable, when I set it in the constructor and the object changes the value of it

Tags: c++, constructor, pass-by-reference

Maybe it's better to show the code then it is better to understand what my problem is.

Class:

```cpp
Cls::Cls() {}
Cls::Cls(int &var) : m_var(var){
    std::cout << "constructor: " << m_var << std::endl;
}
Cls::~Cls() {}

void Cls::setVar() const {
    m_var = 5;
    std::cout << "setVar: " << m_var << std::endl;
}
```

Header:

```cpp
class Cls {

public:
    Cls();
    Cls(int &var);
    virtual ~Cls();
    
    void setVar() const;
    
private:
    mutable int m_var;
};
```

The main:

```cpp
int main() {

    int var = 1;

    Cls *cls;
    cls = new Cls(var);
    cls->setVar();
    
    std::cout << "var: " << var << std::endl;
}
```

So, I passed `var` using the custom constructor `Cls(int &var)`. After it, I call a function changing the value of the variable. I expected, that I would see the change in the `main`. I was wrong. How can I achieve that? I don't want to pass the variable as function argument.

Comment: It should be ` mutable int &m_var`, surely? At present you're just copying the value.

Comment: Yes you pass a reference to `var` to the constructor. But `Cls::m_var` is *not* a reference. When you initialize or assign to it, you're *copying* the value into `m_var`.

Comment: You have two variables here `var` in `main` and `m_var` in `Cls`. They are **different variables**, changing one does not change the other.

Comment: And why did you mark `Cls::m_var` as `mutable`? What problem is that supposed to solve? Your code doesn't deal with constant objects anywhere.

Comment: Also, there's no need for pointers here. Are you coming from a language like C# or Java, where you must use `new` to create objects? That's not needed in C++. I recommend you invest in [some good C++ beginners books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: To achieve what you want you need to change `m_var` to be a reference `int& m_var;`. But that is unlikely to be a good idea, references in classes are not a common thing to have, especially for a beginner.

Answer (score 1):

```
private:
    mutable int m_var;
```

this is not a reference, this is an int, you need:

```
private:
    int& m_var;
```

And since your class has a reference as a member, which must be initialized you cannot have default constructor.

Answer (score 0):

although you pass the `var` in main to `Cls` constructor as reference, but in `Cls` constructor it copies the value of parameter `var` to data member `m_var`. maybe you must declare data member `m_var` as:

```
mutable int& m_var;
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found a solution. It's actually quiet easy.

Class:

```cpp
Cls::Cls() {}
Cls::Cls(int &var) : m_var(&var){
    std::cout << "constructor: " << *m_var << std::endl;
}
Cls::~Cls() {}

void Cls::setVar() const {
    *m_var = 5;
    std::cout << "setVar(): " << *m_var << std::endl;
}
```

Header:

```cpp
class Cls {

public:
    Cls();
    Cls(int &var);
    virtual ~Cls();
    
    void setVar() const;
    
private:
    int *m_var;
};
```

The main:

```cpp
    int var = 1;

    Cls *cls;
    cls = new Cls(var);
    cls->setVar();
    std::cout << "main var 1: " << var << std::endl;
}
```

For those who asked why and how... This is not my actual code. This is an extremely short example showing the problem I have in my code.

Comment: Don't use pointers either! It's actually worse than references in a way. What is the actual and underlying problem this is supposed to solve? Please delete this question, and post a new one where you ask about the actual and underlying problem directly, instead of making it an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). Then we can help you solve that, with better and more appropriate solutions.